# Is Camunda BPM compatible with WildFly 10?

Tags: business-process-management, camunda, wildfly-10

I would like to know whether Camunda compatible with WildFly 10? Isaw WildFly 8 in Camunda downloads. Will these modules work with WildFly 10 as well?

Comment: I am getting following error when I integrated in wildfly 9. [Host Controller] ]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0309: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.threads' is not supported on servers running this version. The extension is only supportedfor use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain"

Answer (score 4):

Camunda added official support for Wildfly 10 with Camunda 7.5.0 which was released yesterday. You can download the [prepackaged Wildfly 10 distro](https://camunda.org/release/camunda-bpm/wildfly10/7.5/) from the website. Or have a look at the [7.5 installation guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/installation/full/jboss/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes Camunda is compatible with wildfly 10 and the modules should work fine. Are you facing any specific error, what have you tried? The detailed installation guide can be found [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/runtime-container-integration/jboss/).

BR